# git describe --tags outputting additional information

Tags: git

I want to get the current tag of the commit checked out.

I'm using the command `git describe --tags`. This works well for me.

I noticed though sometimes when I am on a commit that doesn't have a tag it will spit out additional information along with the *last tag*.

```
git describe --tags
1.0-138-g1602570b
```

1.0 is the *last tag* and there are two other components, `138` and `g1602570b`. I thought `138` was the # of commits between HEAD and the *last tag* but that doesn't match up. I thought `g1602570b` was the current commit but that doesn't match up either.

Does anyone know what information is provided?

Comment: Have you thought of checking the `git tag` docs?  `git tag --points-at`.

Comment: It should be `g`, not `z`. See [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe), particularly the EXAMPLES section. The count *is* the number of commits between (really, after) the tag, before the hash; remember that this count may include additional branches!

Comment: @torek I get that part of the question, I can't find any variation on `git rev-list --count` that gives the same count as `git describe` does.

Comment: @jthill: Hm, documentation *claims* it's what you'd get with `git rev-list --count <tag>..HEAD`. The internals of `git describe` are ... squirrelly, though, so maybe something else is off here.

Comment: @torek yeah, I bounced off describe.c too, not worth getting in to, particularly because that's an eyeball number to give some idea how close the tip is, git rev-parse doesn't check it.

Comment: @torek Thanks for the correction, looks like the commit "without" the g matches up with the current commit. Interesting that the count may include additional branches, makes sense.